# Neo4J server exception - fails to start

Tags: neo4j

The server had been running fine and dandy but suddenly stopped. Tried restarting but that didn't help. This is what the log says:

```
2015-02-18 15:07:58.092+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- SHUTDOWN diagnostics END ---
2015-02-18 15:07:58.336+0000 ERROR [o.n.s.CommunityBootstrapper]: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:226) ~[neo4j-server-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108) [neo4j-server-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62) [neo4j-server-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:366) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:123) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:65) ~[neo4j-server-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:71) ~[neo4j-server-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:362) ~[neo4j-server-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:159) ~[neo4j-server-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@7bd760a1' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:82) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to lock org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel@c8925d7
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.wrapFileChannelLock(FileLock.java:38) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:93) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:93) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
```

**UPDATE**

Acted upon the advice given in the answer but unfortunately the server still doesn't start. neo4j start command has been waiting for server to start for the last 10 minutes:

> Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
>   -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user process [29578]... waiting for
>   server to be ready.........

The log file says:

```
2015-02-18 15:50:09.958+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: [/var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1] entries found=91485 lastEntryPos=5328191
2015-02-18 15:50:09.958+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Opened logical log [/var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1] version=8, lastTxId=513504 (recovered)
2015-02-18 15:50:09.959+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: XaResourceManager[nioneo_logical.log] sorting 0 xids
2015-02-18 15:50:09.997+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: XaResourceManager[nioneo_logical.log] checkRecoveryComplete 0 xids
2015-02-18 15:50:10.407+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names rebuild id generator, highId=35 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:10.490+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names rebuild id generator, highId=17 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:10.571+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db rebuild id generator, highId=16 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:10.653+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys rebuild id generator, highId=49 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:10.776+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index rebuild id generator, highId=44 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:10.819+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings rebuild id generator, highId=41 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:11.101+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays rebuild id generator, highId=7954 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:15.753+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db rebuild id generator, highId=212690 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:19.113+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db rebuild id generator, highId=234591 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:19.155+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels rebuild id generator, highId=1 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:20.131+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db rebuild id generator, highId=46820 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:20.194+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db rebuild id generator, highId=5 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:20.300+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db rebuild id generator, highId=14508 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:20.423+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/neostore rebuild id generator, highId=9 defragged count=0
2015-02-18 15:50:20.424+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: XaResourceManager[nioneo_logical.log] recovery completed.
2015-02-18 15:50:20.424+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Recovery on log [/var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1] completed.
2015-02-18 15:50:20.628+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.TxManager]: TM opening log: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/tm_tx_log.2
2015-02-18 15:50:20.992+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/index/lucene.log.1]. Recovery started ...
2015-02-18 15:50:20.992+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: [/var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/index/lucene.log.1] logVersion=2 with committed tx=199234
```

My server previously had around 50K nodes and 300K relationships. Is the server attempting to recover the data, and hence causing the delay in starting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message

```
 org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
```

is pretty much self speaking. You either don't have the file system permission to access your `graph.db` folder or (which I think is more probable) that there is still another Neo4j process running on the same `graph.db` directory. You can check for running processes using the usual suspects like `jps` or `ps aux | grep java`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Stefan. Unfortunately, I still don't have luck starting the server. I have updated my answer with log file message. I am also wondering why the server suddenly stopped running - what could have caused it? Would appreciate pointers, thanks.

Comment: Depending on the size of your graph this can be expected behaviour. When you do a unclean shutdown (killing the process, power off) Neo4j will detect this upon start up and do some recovery/sanity checks that might take some time.

Comment: If you are **sure** that no other server is running on the same directory you can also delete the store_lock file.

Comment: Solved my problem. It seems when starting neo4j for the first time, it consumes some time. Starting again before the first start complete leads to such problem. I killed the hidden neo4j, then started it and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with message **Unable to obtain a lock on store lock file (...)**

What happened? When I was setting up graph.db, acting as sudo, the owner was obviously root/root. Neo4j process was not allowed to access the place.

The solution which worked for me was to change the owner of graph.db folder with:

```
chown -R neo4j.neo4j /path/to/graphdb/graph.db/
```