# neo4j 3.0 (community edition) - unable to start server on debian 8

Tags: neo4j, debian

I tried neo4j 3.0 on two machines.

1. Had a working neo4j 2.x and upgraded to neo4j 3.0 through apt-get upgrade
2. Fresh installation of neo4j 3.0

In both cases, neo4j does not start and I see the following error message
[console]

```
sudo service neo4j start
Job for neo4j.service failed. See 'systemctl status neo4j.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

$ sudo systemctl status neo4j.service -l
● neo4j.service - LSB: Neo4j Graph Database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/neo4j)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-05-05 18:24:14 UTC; 8min ago
  Process: 1377 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/neo4j start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 05 18:24:14 abc-com neo4j[1377]: Starting Neo4j.
May 05 18:24:14 abc-com neo4j[1377]: WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
May 05 18:24:14 abc-com neo4j[1377]: /usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 149: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory
May 05 18:24:14 abc-com systemd[1]: neo4j.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 05 18:24:14 abc-com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Neo4j Graph Database server.
May 05 18:24:14 abc-com systemd[1]: Unit neo4j.service entered failed state.

cat /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Store and its lock file has been locked by another process: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLocker.storeLockException(StoreLocker.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:76)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: when you did the fresh install, did you remove the old version first?

Comment: @rcheuk there was no old version of neo4j in the system

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587032/neo4j-server-exception-fails-to-start

Comment: The following hack solves this problem

`sudo mkdir /var/run/neo4j
sudo touch /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid`

Comment: Looks like the script that brings up the server expects the directory and file to exist and does not create it if it is missing...also note that the debian 8 instance is on Google Cloud Platform. Not sure it if makes any difference.

Comment: If you `sudo mkdir /var/run/neo4j && sudo chown neo4j /var/run/neo4j`, the server is able to create `neo4j.pid`.